# Can any one give me Dotnetnuke module localization with example

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

please any one can provide me a good example of dotnetnuke module localization....i am new to DNN...thanks..

**Edit** : I have googled a lot haven't found any good example

Comment: Did you at least Google? [my first search on Google](http://www.adefwebserver.com/dotnetnukehelp/Localization/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

first add your language to DNN (in DNN6 go to Admin -->languages and add your language)
your module have App_LocalResouces folder .this folder have resx files.for localization you must use this files. for every resx file you must add a new resx file for your language. for example if your culture name is "fa-IR", and you have a resx file with name "Edit.ascx.resx", you should make a copy from this file and change name of this copy to "Edit.ascx.fa-IR.resx" . and then translate this new resx file items to your language
if you want to add items to this resx file you should use resoursekey element in your ascx file  for example:

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblExample" runat="server" resourcekey="lblExample">
```

and then in both resx files add lblExample key and its value
if you want use value of this controls in your code add this to your code

```
  string lblMessage;
  lblMessage = Localization.GetString("lblExample", this.LocalResourceFile);
```

you can replace "this.LocalResourceFile" with address of your resx file

Comment: Thanks for answer...I have tried and it worked as charm...thank you..:)